# How to avoid using ON CONFLICT DO ' 'NOTHING' on Django?

Tags: django, postgresql-9.4

I have an webapp running in a CentOS Server with Django 3.0 and PostgreSQL 9.4.25. Cant upgrade ph right now.

On this wepapp there are many queries generated by django that look like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.cad_uf
(nome, sigla, regiao_id)
VALUES('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 0) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

The problem is that "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" is not available on this pg version (9.4.25).

How can I make django dont generate this ending code in SQL, looking like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.cad_uf
(nome, sigla, regiao_id)
VALUES('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 0);
```

Comment: Any news? I've got exactly the same problem. Stuck by my shared host with PostgreSQL 9.2.24...

Comment: Nothing new so far... Features like this should be backward compatible, being disabled by some configuration